# Update property in 3 level of nested array of entities in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there a straight forward way to update nested array of entities in MongoDB. I am using MongoDB C# Driver for making the DB call from application. Below is an exmaple : say I have a Student collection where each document has a nested array of Course with some necessary fields populated and Course by itself is a separate collection like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "234dssfcv456",
    "Name": "Jean Douglas",
    "Age": 32,
    "Courses": [
      {
        "_id": "1234",
        "Name": "Computer Science",
        "Level": "Basic",
        "Lectures": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "3456",
        "Name": "Bio Science",
        "Level": "Intermediate",
        "Lectures": [
          {
            "_id": 433,
            "Name": "lectture1"
          },
          {
            "_id": 1234,
            "Name": "lectture1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here my code of updating the Name of lecture

```
var _client = new MongoClient(@"....");
  var _database = _client.GetDatabase("...");
  var _students =  _database.GetCollection<Student>("students");

  var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter;
  var studentIdAndCourseIdFilter = filter.And(
    filter.Eq(x => x.Id, "234dssfcv456"),
    filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Courses, c => c.Id == "1234")
    filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Courses.FirstMatchingElement().Lectures, c => c.Id == "433")    );
   // find student with id and course id
   var student = _students.Find(studentIdAndCourseIdFilter).SingleOrDefault();

  // update with positional operator
  var update = Builders<Student>.Update;      
  var courseLevelSetter = update.Set("Courses.$.Lectures.$.Name", "Updated Name");
  _students.UpdateOne(studentIdAndCourseIdFilter, courseLevelSetter);
```

But I get the error : Too many positional (i.e '$') elements foundin path

could someone help my too undestandt how to update the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$arrayFilters` like this:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  {_id: "234dssfcv456"},
  {$set: {"Courses.$[c].Lectures.$[l].Name": "Updated Name"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"c._id": "3456"}, {"l._id": 433}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3lBPjns21cd)